# Django ORM bulk create_or_update + delete not updated

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

```
class Item(Model):
    article = CharField
    owner = ForeignKey(User)
    price = IntegerField
    stock = IntegerField
```

Hello, pls me help with bulk create_or_update_or_delete logic.

I have an Items in db.
Then I have a new list of items.
items = (Item, Item, Item...)
but without price field
i want to

1. bulk create items that already not in DB (using article and owner) with price = Null
2. bulk update existing items(but not update price)
3. bulk delete those items, that previously existed in db, but not updated in step 2.

I know how to bulk create_or_update but idk how to add in step 3 and make all of that efficient.

I cant just delete all owner's items and then bulk_create cuz I lost price data.

Comment: For existing items, what field(s) are matched against (what makes it an existing item) and what field(s) are updated?

Comment: `I know how to bulk create_or_update` -- Didn't know this was possible. How was it implemented?

Comment: matching article and owner. update only stock.